# cannot write value into file via PHP

Tags: php

I have a configuration file like the following,

```
NameA=3
NameB=2
NameC=1
```

The following code tries to find NameC, and replace its value. Suppose here I pass in the value 0.

```
public function writeScreenSwitch($isTick)
{
    $filename = 'my/file/path';
    $data = parse_ini_file($filename);
    $replace_with = array(
      'NameC' => $isTick
    ); 
    // After print out $replace_with value, I'm sure the value is,
    //     [NameC] => 0

    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
    {
       if ( !empty($replace_with[$key]) ) {
          $value = $replace_with[$key];
       } else {
          echo "array empty";   
          // the problem is here.
          // $replace_with[$key] is always empty.
          // but before the loop, the value $replace_with['NameC']=0
          // why.
       }

       fwrite($fh, "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

I have described the problem on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the [empty()](http://php.net/empty) function, have a look at the remarks in the Return Values section.
What you're needing to check for is if it is set, using the isset() function:

```
public function writeScreenSwitch($isTick)
{
    $filename = 'my/file/path';
    $data = parse_ini_file($filename);
    $replace_with = array(
      'NameC' => $isTick
    ); 
    // After print out $replace_with value, I'm sure the value is,
    //     [NameC] => 0

    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w');
    foreach ( $data as $key => $value )
    {
       if ( isset($replace_with[$key]) ) {
          $value = $replace_with[$key];
       } else {
          echo "array not set";   
          // the problem is here.
          // $replace_with[$key] is always empty.
          // but before the loop, the value $replace_with['NameC']=0
          // why.
       }

       fwrite($fh, "{$key}={$value}" . PHP_EOL);
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

That should do the trick.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because 0 is counted as EMPTY. That's why you are getting this.

Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)